# Angular 1/ui-select/Jasmine - Test element if exist inside ng-if

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ui-select

I want to test the existence of an input that is inside an `ng-if`, without the ng-if the test passes perfectly but not with the `ng-if`.

In my template i have :

```
  <div ng-if="$ctrl.doShowAir">
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
  </div>
```

The `doShowAir` Is a variable within a function `doShow()` which should be `true` when choosing a choice in a previous ui-select

```
  <ui-select ng-model="$ctrl.parking.parkingType"
             on-select="$ctrl.doShow()">
    <ui-select-match>
      <span>{{ $select.selected.label }}</span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in $ctrl.projectReferences.parkingType | filter: { label: $select.search }">
      <span ng-bind-html="item.label"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Function :

```
  doShow() {
    this.doShowAir = (this.parkingType.labelKey === 'parking_type.air')
  }
```

And the unit test :

```
import angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'

let scope
let rootScope
let compile
let htmlElement
let ctrl

fdescribe('projectExteriorParking', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('ProjectExteriorParkingModule')
    angular.mock.module('ui.select')
  })

  beforeEach(inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_) => {
    rootScope = _$rootScope_
    compile = _$compile_
    scope = rootScope.$new()
    scope.parking = {}
    htmlElement = compile(`<project-exterior-parking parking="project.realEstateProjectProduct.parkings"></project-exterior-parking>`)(scope)
    rootScope.$digest()
  }))

  beforeEach(inject(($componentController) => {
    let bindings = {
      parking: {},
      projectReferences: {}
    }
    ctrl = $componentController('projectExteriorParkingModule', null, bindings)
  }))

  it('should contain two input', () => {
    const inputItems = htmlElement.get(0).querySelectorAll('input')
    expect(inputItems.length).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

How can I simulate that the variable `shouldShowAir` is true, or simulate the choice `on-select="$ctrl.doShow()"` on the ui-select which invokes the function Because I do not have access to the `doShow()` function.
Or how to "manually" add the input to the test and compile it in addition to `<project-exterior-parking parking="project.realEstateProjectProduct.parkings"></project-exterior-parking>`

Comment: 1. What are you trying to do with: `ctrl = $componentController('projectExteriorParkingModule', null, bindings)`  in the second `beforeEach` block? Is this an attempt to get the controller of the compiled component above? You can get the element controller with `htmlElement.controller('projectExteriorParking')`

Answer (score 0):

To get the controller of a compiled element you call `ctrl = htmlElement.controller('directive|component name')`

In your case `ctrl = htmlElement.controller('projectExteriorParking')`

`directive|component` is the string you provide when you register components or directives to an `angular.module`

Knowing how to get the controller from the compiled htmlElement you can now call `ctrl.doShow()` and `$rootScope.$apply()` and then assert that the element is rendered the way you do in the test

There are a couple of other things in you code:
`ng-model="$ctrl.parking.parkingType"`

```
doShow() {
  // ngModel is this.parking.parkingType
  // is there this.parkingType or is this a mistake?
  this.doShowAir = (this.parkingType.labelKey ===  'parking_type.air')
}
```

The scope you pass to $compile lacks the requires bindings:

```
beforeEach(inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_) => {
  rootScope = _$rootScope_
  compile = _$compile_
  scope = rootScope.$new()
  scope.parking = {}
  // The compiled element has `parking` bound to `project.realEstate...` yet you don't have it on scope
 // you should assign some mock data as `scope.project = { realEstateProjectProduct }`
  htmlElement = compile(`<project-exterior-parking parking="project.realEstateProjectProduct.parkings"></project-exterior-parking>`)(scope)
  rootScope.$digest()
```

}))

You should pass some mock data and or set `ctrl.parkingType` to a value that you **expect** will make the method `ctrl.doShow()` set `ctrl.doShowAir` to true